# CK Editor 5 Paste From Word plugin does not work

Tags: angular, plugins, ckeditor, angular9, ckeditor5

I have been trying to implement the PasteFromOffice plugin for CK Editor 5 and have been having a lot of trouble. I am working with Angular 9 for a project at my job.

I have tried with the Decoupled and Classic Editor but after some research saw that plugins work better with CustomBuilds. I have created a Custom build following this link:

https://ckeditor.com/ckeditor-5/online-builder/

I have chosen the PasteFromOffice plugin, along with many other plugin's and it seems that the only one that does not function properly is the PasteFromOffice plugin.

I can confirm this because I downloaded the provided MS Word file from the link above and copy and pasted its contents to the editor on the page and it worked as expected. However, when running my counterpart and pasting the contents of the Word file to the editor I am running on my computer, it is formatted differently and is NOT the same as on the editor in the link above.

When I try to add:

import PasteFromOffice from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-paste-from-office/src/pastefromoffice';

to the editorConfig, I get an error about duplicate modules, and I fully understand that is because I am importing duplicate dependencies in importing PasteFromOffice and setting it in 'config.plugins'.

My question now is, what is the proper way to implement PasteFromOffice plugin for CK Editor 5??

Comment: Just wanted to add that there is a 'sample' folder that contains 'index.html' to show what current plugins and tools work on your newly downloaded custom build. Upon opening, it still does NOT contain the functionality for PasteFromOffice.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. You can't add a plugin to an existing build you must create another one.
https://ckeditor.com/ckeditor-5/online-builder/